# Inhibit the executable from file system modification

Tags: linux

I am on Linux. I have a directory and an executable. How can I inhibit the executable from the directory modification?

`chmod a-w -R dir` is executed too much time. Any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the immutable flag on the file. This will prevent the file data and its attributes from being modified (chmod will simply fail on that file)

```
chattr +i /path/to/myfile
```